# Is there any specific article about every options of REST in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I wanna use rails REST so:

```
resources :questions
```

I wanna add a route /questions/query_by_student so:

```
resources :questions, :collection => { :query_by_student => :get }
```

now I want /questions/query_by_student/1 this 1 shoule be student`s id .What I should do？
Even more,I want the request which post to /questions/query_by_student/1 meet another action...

我想用rails的REST 于是：
`resources :questions`
我想添加一个/questions/query_by_student 于是：
`resources :questions, :collection => { :query_by_student => :get }`
现在我想/questions/query_by_student/1 这个1是student的id 我要怎么写？

Comment: It gives me my page "query_by_student.html".Is that related？

Comment: Just "got here" typed by myself...

Comment: just like the link says,some questions limited by the student.I can make that by generate url like "/questions/query_by_student?id=1",but I want to make it more RESTful...

Comment: so you want a route `/questions/query_by_student/1` to be recognized and processed by your controller right? Do you also need `/questions/query_by_student` route to be available?

Comment: no. And my school will cut the net soon,feed back to you tomorrow...

Comment: try `resources :questions, :member => { :query_by_student => :get }`

Comment: Are you sure that is helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your routes.rb

```
    match ':controller/:id/:action'
```

Your controller would have:

```
   def query_by_student
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    ...
   end
```